socket.io not connecting in production/on server but, works perfectly on localhost
I have a MERN app, I use socket.io for a web socket functionality. This is my code and configuration:
index.js:
// Import required modules
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const connectToMongo = require("./mongo/dbConnection");
require("dotenv").config();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");

// Create Express app
const app = express();
connectToMongo();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// ------- ROUTES -------
app.use('/api/', require('path to file'))

// Serving WS and Express servers together
const server = http.createServer(app);
global.io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected:", socket.id);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected:", socket.id);
  });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Socket Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

[IMPORTED ROUTE IN INDEX.JS]
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../../mongo/schema/userSchema");
const Request = require("../../mongo/schema/requestSchema");
const fetchUser = require("../userAuth/fetchUserMiddleware");

router.post("/history", fetchUser, async (req, res) => {
  const filterCount = 10;
  const trialFilterCount = 3;
  try {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    const historyData = await Request.find({ userId: userId })
      .select(["-_id", "-__v", "-userId"])
      .sort({ timestamp: -1 });

    if (
      historyData.length >= trialFilterCount &&
      user.subscriptionType === "trial"
    ) {
      await user.updateOne({ subscriptionType: "notSubscribed" });

      global.io.emit("subscriptionStatusChange", { subStatus: false });
    }
    const userHistory = historyData.slice(0, filterCount);

    res.status(200).send({ success: true, userHistory });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in Filter History fetching\n" + error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error!");
  }
});

module.exports = router;


[nginx conf]
server {
    server_name www.<app>.com;

    # Serve frontend files
    location / {
        root /var/www/<app>/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /socket/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

The whole app works absolutely perfectly on localhost, but it does not work at all on the server (VPS). What can I try next? The problem is that the web socket connection is not establishing at all. I am calling the socket.io client in frontend like this:
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const AuthContext = createContext();
const backendHost = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_HOST;

const socket = io(`${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_SOCKET_HOST}`);

socket.on('connect',()=>{
  console.log('Socket Connected')
})

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [isSubscribed, setIsSubscribed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    socket.on("subscriptionStatusChange", ({ subStatus }) => {
      setIsSubscribed(subStatus);
    });

    // Clean up
    // return () => {
    //   socket.off("subscriptionStatusChange");
    // };
  }, []);



  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSubscribed,
        setIsSubscribed
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;

More info: I am using GCP VM instance. Firewall allows http connections.
I tried pinging the web socket as standalone instance on localhost on VPS it connects, but not through the website.
const net = require('net');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1'; // localhost
const PORT = 5000; // Port number to connect to

// Create a TCP socket client
const client = new net.Socket();

// Attempt to connect to the server
client.connect(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Connected to ${HOST}:${PORT}`);

    // Once connected, send a message to the server
    client.write('Hello, server! I am a client.');
});

// Handle incoming data from the server
client.on('subscriptionStatusChange', (data) => {
    console.log(`Received data from server: ${data}`);

    // Close the connection after receiving data
    client.end();
});

// Handle connection closed by the server
client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection closed by server');
});

// Handle connection errors
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
});


What port are you using? If it is not 443 (or 80) then you might have to add extra inbound rules on your GCP VM.

@halfer, I am using 5000 for my backend (both express and websocket served on same port). But, i don't need to allow that as i am using reverse porxy, see the nginxx conf file.
and, the express part works perfectly, just the web socket connection not establishing

So the frontend is loaded from port 443, and the HTTP backend and the websocket are on port 5000? Well, it sounds like a firewall in GCP is getting in the way.

Now there may be (should be) a way you can debug this in GCP, but I am not sure that using anything other than port 443 is advisable anyway. On mobile or corporate networks, non-standard ports can get blocked by excessive firewall policies. Can you get your app to run from a single port?

i'm using react and express, not next. It is not possible (as far as I know),  to run them on same port.

Yes, it is entirely possible to run them on the same port. I don't know if it can be done with Nginx as a frontend "load balancer", but Traefik can do it. It can differentiate between HTTPS and web sockets, and between HTTPS frontend and HTTPS APIs, using a variety of packet examination strategies.

you see, i just tried using the same configuration on a vmware Ubuntu vm at its localhost. It works perfect but, it jsut does not work on the VPS. I used the same Nginx configuration (backend and frontend on different ports), it works on a local VM but not the VPS

Yes. You probably have a GCP firewall in the way.

No, I tried using the same configuration on a DigitalOcean VM, no firewall rules. Still the same issue. WebSocket just won't connect

I have moved to server polling. I have to deliver the project. So, in case you ever find the reason. Do answer here. Thanks.

Another thing to try is related to the question you asked 9 months ago. In that question you learned the difference between listeners on 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0. I don't think that this is the answer here, since Nginx can listen on 0.0.0.0 and your app endpoints could listen on 127.0.0.1, since Nginx just connects locally. But it may be worth experimenting with this idea.

@halfer, I found the solution after searching deep through socket.io docs. The problem is using an http server on a http(S) website. Since I have an SSL for my domains, I needed to use an https server for socket and also, need to supply the SSL certificate and key to the server options.
I'll upload the proper solution once I get some spare time.
Nonetheless, thanks for giving your time to my problem.
